# Executable Jar, how to set the application name?

Tags: java, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

When bulding a executable jar with the maven-assembly-plugin and afterwards running it, it is recognized as a java application.

How could I manage that the jar is listed with it's application name ?

My POM:

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>package.mainclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven gives you control over the name of your deliverable by using the finalName element, as in:

```
<!-- Inside your pom.xml -->
<build>
   <finalName>whateverIWantToCallMyDeliverable</finalName>
</build>
```

May this suit you?

Comment: Well, I have tried this, but it only modifies the Output FileName, isn't it? I would like to be able e.g. in windows open the task manager and then find my running application via it's name(otherwise it is listed as java.exe)... I could package it with Launch4J, but that's a bit of an overload for a commandline application:)

Comment: I think a launcher program is probably your only option. I think changing a process name under Windows requires Administrator privileges, and use of APIs that aren't available from Java.

Comment: Well, lets wait for some more opinions, but I already feared that